# С++ Глобальные параметры в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gtk

Windows 10 Home 64 bit, Visual Studio 2019 Community. Раньше делал GTK приложения в CodeBlocks, там можно было задать глобальный параметр gtk, указать поддиректории bin, include, lib директории с GTK, и далее можно было работать с кодом без сложных настроек (в отладочной и релизной конфигурации ничего менять не нужно было). В VS 2019 мне приходится в параметры проекта добавлять кучу директорий в параметры проекта отдельно для отладочной и релизной конфигурации. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как упростить настройку VS2019 для работы с GTK.

Comment: Это cmake - с ним вы отвяжитесь от ide и ваш проект перестанет зависеть от какой-либо ide

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=vs-2019

Comment: Да мне удобнее программировать в IDE